# How to paste to a specific column with python excel

Tags: python, excel, csv, openpyxl

I am wanting to copy and paste data from a csv to an excel so I can later filter that table.  I have done all these steps in VBA but I've noticed that VBA can be buggy so am wanting to migrate to Python.

I have converted the csv to an excel and I have successfully copied the converted xlsx file to the excel document.

My question is, how do I copy and paste to a specific starting column.   As I have other data I need to copy at `cell AN1.`

I have tried the below..  I am able to write to one specific cell but I am wanting to post the data...

```
   for row in ws1:
        for cell in row:
            ws2['K1'].value
            #ws2[cell.coordinate].value = cell.value
    wb2.save(path2)
```

Entirety...

```
  ## csv to xlsx

from openpyxl import Workbook
import csv


wb = Workbook()
ws = wb.active
with open('C:/B.csv', 'r') as f:
    for row in csv.reader(f):
        ws.append(row)
wb.save('C:/B.xlsx')


###### COPY FROM B to existing E workbook


import openpyxl as xl


path1 = 'C:/B.xlsx'
path2 = 'C:/E.xlsx'

wb1 = xl.load_workbook(filename=path1)
ws1 = wb1.worksheets[0]

wb2 = xl.load_workbook(filename=path2)
ws2 = wb2.worksheets[0]
#ws2 = wb2.create_sheet(ws1.title)

#cell.value = ['A2']
for row in ws1:
    for cell in row:
        ws2.cell(row=1, column=1).value = cell.value
wb2.save(path2)
```

Comment: I assume your data is all start value 1.  You might want to incorporate copy from columns values to paste column values

Comment: Do you mean copy column `A` from `B.xlsx` to column `AN` in `E.xlsx`?

Comment: @MartinEvans  The data is dynamic so it varies, but in this case B:E.xlsx -> AN in xlsx.

Comment: Use pandas over openpyxl it is a lot easier and more documentation

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Copying columns between two different workbooks using `openpyxl` could be done as follows:

```
import openpyxl

wb1 = openpyxl.load_workbook('B.xlsx')
ws1 = wb1.active

wb2 = openpyxl.load_workbook('E.xlsx')
ws2 = wb2.active

for src, dst in zip(ws1['B:B'], ws2['AN:AN']):
    dst.value = src.value

wb2.save('E.xlsx')
```

---

For a range of columns, the following would work:

```
import openpyxl

wb1 = openpyxl.load_workbook('B.xlsx')
ws1 = wb1.active

wb2 = openpyxl.load_workbook('E.xlsx')
ws2 = wb2.active

for src, dst in zip(ws1['A:I'], ws2['AN:AV']):
    for cell_src, cell_dst in zip(src, dst):
        cell_dst.value = cell_src.value

wb2.save('E.xlsx')
```

Comment: Is there no way to copy a cell range like in VBA?  Say the data is A:I -> AN->AS.  That would create quite lengthy code.

Comment: How would that work? They are two different sizes? `A:I` to `AN:AV` perhaps?

Comment: Oh yes that's what I meant.  They're the same size

Comment: Works perfectly. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

```
for row in range(1, ws1.max_row + 1):
    #for cell in row:
    ws1.column_dimensions.group('A', 'D', hidden=True)
    sheet.cell(row=i + 2, column=k + 1).value = val
wb2.save(path2)
```

Should do it

Comment: I get     sheet.cell(row=i + 2, column=k + 1).value = val
NameError: name 'val' is not defined

Answer (score -1):

Unfortunately the solutions provide were very much unacceptable as they did not work. VBA is also off the table. I am using openpyxl and the above created an error.  Ideally I would like to copy to a new column, but that is beyond my skill.  Instead use the below and use excel formulas to get the data where you want. I will have to spend about 4 hours redesigning my excel but worth it I suppose as I am unable to find a workaround.

```
## csv to xlsx

from openpyxl import Workbook
import csv


wb = Workbook()
ws = wb.active
with open('C/B.csv', 'r') as f:
    for row in csv.reader(f):
        ws.append(row)
wb.save('C:/B.xlsx')


###### COPY FROM B to existing E workbook


import openpyxl as xl


path1 = 'C:/B.xlsx'
path2 = 'C:/E.xlsx'

wb1 = xl.load_workbook(filename=path1)
ws1 = wb1.worksheets[0]

wb2 = xl.load_workbook(filename=path2)
ws2 = wb2.worksheets[0]
#ws2 = wb2.create_sheet(ws1.title)

#cell.value = ['A2']
for row in ws1:
    for cell in row:
        ws2[cell.coordinate].value = cell.value
wb2.save(path2)
```

Comment: It doesn't look to me like the suggestions wouldn't work but more like your question is vague and you don't seem to understand the openpyxl API.

Comment: @CharlieClark Fair point.  I read the documentation but not much on writing to specific columns.  largely single values.

Comment: @Wman Did you re-try Vlad's solution?  There is no way to do this easily in python but Vlad's solution should work for you.

Comment: @ChellWheatly I tend to favour python over Vba for simplicity and reliability.

Comment: Anyway I strongly suggest that you read over other answers in stackoverflow as this question has likely already been solved.